# Openshift KeystoneJS NodeJS app - missing dependency

Tags: node.js, openshift, keystonejs

I have tried to deploy my KeystoneJS app which was running just fine on my local environment to Openshift NodeJS cartridge and I keep getting dependency errors like this:

```
==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log-20161031064556 <==
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:472:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:420:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:500:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/5816407e89f5cfcee800001c/app-root/runtime/repo/app.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:490:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:449:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:441:3)
module.js:474
    throw err;
^
```

When I try to find the `dotenv` module, it's present in the `node_modules` directory:

```
ls -la node_modules/ | grep dotenv
drwx------.   3 xyz xyz  4096 31. říj 07.56 dotenv
```

The other error I keep getting is:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:545:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:490:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:449:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:441:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:500:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at symbols (/var/lib/openshift/5816407e89f5cfcee800001c/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/slug/slug.js:6:16)
    at /var/lib/openshift/5816407e89f5cfcee800001c/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/slug/slug.js:201:5
/var/lib/openshift/5816407e89f5cfcee800001c/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/unicode/category/So.js:2
});
```

Which is also not present in my local env. (but I think this one would disappear when I resolve the first error)

I tried to reinstall the app using:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clear
npm install
```

several times, but without a success.

Version of NodeJS is

```
node --version
v7.0.0
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

shimon

Answer (score 0):

If there is a syntax error on server only then you failed to deploy the new version.

Also, check the module name in `dotenv` package.json or readme.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I've checked the package.json file of `dotenv` module. The `name` atribute is set to `dotenv`. Version is `2.0.0`